# How to configure HUAWEI smartAX MT882 modem on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, drivers, adsl-router

I am using USB to connect the modem to my pc. can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

According to [the manual](http://www.talktalkmembers.com/images/downloads/manuals/SmartAXMT882_ADSL_Router_User_Manual.pdf) there are Linux drivers on the CD, but it looks quite a pain and may be completely out of date (the manual talks about the 2.4 kernel).

As I understand it the MT882 has an Ethernet connection you can plug in as an alternative to USB. You should use this whatever OS you're on as it will just work without any special drivers (the Windows drivers for USB modems are themselves traditionally notoriously unreliable).

Comment: I dont have a Ethernet port on my PC , as there is no slot for it on the motherboard.
So USB is the only option for me.

Comment: A PC with no network socket?! Wow, I didn't know such things existed still! It might well be worth picking up a dirt-cheap PCI Ethernet card; I can't imagine how I'd get on without being able to connect to a LAN.

Comment: @Nikhil - I think you're pretty much out of luck. Please for PCI slots - they *should* be available.

Answer (score 0):

If your Spanish is any good, there is a walkthrough on [this page](http://www.ubuntu-es.org/index.php?q=node/19203).

This is a [Google Translate version](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&layout=2&eotf=1&u=http://www.ubuntu-es.org/index.php?q=node/19203&act=url) as well (but the translation doesn't look really easy to follow).